# How to fix "realloc(): invalid pointer"

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to write a function to convert a text file into a CSV file.
The input file has 3 lines with space-delimited entries. I have to find a way to read a line into a string and transform the three lines from the input file to three columns in a CSV file.

The files look like this :

```
Jake Ali Maria
24 23 43
Montreal Johannesburg Sydney
```

And I have to transform it into something like this:

```
Jake, 24, Montreal
...etc
```

I figured I could create a `char **line` variable that would hold three references to three separate `char` arrays, one for each of the three lines of the input file. I.e., my goal is to have `*(line+i)` store the `i+1`'th line of the file.

I wanted to avoid hardcoding `char` array sizes, such as

```
char line1 [999]; 
fgets(line1, 999, file);
```

so I wrote a while loop to `fgets` pieces of a line into a small buffer array of predetermined size, and then `strcat` and `realloc` memory as necessary to store the line as a string, with `*(line+i)` as as pointer to the string, where `i` is `0` for the first line, `1` for the second, etc.

Here is the problematic code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define CHUNK 10

char** getLines (const char * filename){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rt");
    char **lines = (char ** ) calloc(3, sizeof(char*));
    char buffer[CHUNK];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        int lineLength = 0;
        int bufferLength = 0;
        *(lines+i) = NULL;
        do{
            fgets(buffer, CHUNK, file);
            buffLength = strlen(buffer);
            lineLength += buffLength;
            *(lines+i) = (char*) realloc(*(lines+i), (lineLength +1)*sizeof(char));
            strcat(*(lines+i), buffer);
        }while(bufferLength ==CHUNK-1);
    }
    puts(*(lines+0));
    puts(*(lines+1));
    puts(*(lines+2));

    fclose(file);
}

void load_and_convert(const char* filename){
    char ** lines = getLines(filename);
}

int main(){
    const char* filename = "demo.txt";
    load_and_convert(filename);
}
```

This works as expected only for `i=0`. However, going through this with GDB, I see that I get a `realloc(): invalid pointer` error. The buffer loads fine, and it only crashes when I call 'realloc' in the for loop for `i=1`, when I get to the second line.

I managed to store the strings like I wanted in a small example I did to try to see what was going on, but the inputs were all on the same line. Maybe this has to do with `fgets` reading from a new line?

I would really appreciate some help with this, I've been stuck all day.

Thanks a lot!

***edit

I tried as suggested to use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to initialize the variable `**lines`, but I still have the same issue.I have added the modifications to the original code I uploaded.

***edit

After deleting the file and recompiling, the above now seems to work. Thank you to everyone for helping me out!

Comment: You allocate `line` (which is a misnomer since it's not a single line), which is a pointer to three `char*`s.  You never initialize the contents of `line` (that is, you never make any of those three `char*`s point anywhere).  Consequently, when you do `realloc(*(line + i), ...)`, the first argument is uninitialized garbage.

Comment: You need to initialize the values in `line`.  Also, don't use `*(line + i)`, just use `line[i]` instead, which is equivalent and much clearer.

Comment: `puts(*(lines+0));`  :: No, you dont. Please learn indexing.

Comment: @wildplasser what are you trying to say?

Comment: @wildplasser While it is indeed ugly, it is perfectly correct.

Comment: `void load_and_convert` has no way to return `lines` back to the caller. All it does is create a *memory-leak*.

Comment: You are being your own worst enemy with `#define CHUNK 10`. Why? It violates the fundamental rule *Never Skimp on Buffer Size!* It's far better to give your self the best chance of reading a line at a time rather than reading it piecemeal. This will become glaringly apparent when you actually begin the process of transposing the columns of data into lines of `.csv` output. You will want to store a line of data in the block of memory pointed to by each `lines[i]` pointer, then build another `char**` for `.csv` output. (hint: your `CHUNK-1` test does not handle validation correctly)

Comment: Additionally, will you ever have a data file that has more fields per-line than lines? If so, you will want to carefully plan ahead. Data files containing, e.g. `"Jake Ali Maria Sam"`, and `"24 23 43 31"`, etc... Will take significantly more effort to handle than data files that just happen to have an equal number of fields and lines.

Comment: @David C. Rankin I realize I need to return the lines pointer. This code was a first step to see if I could even store the lines in the first place, hence the print statements. I know also it isn’t fully general, and it would be easier to have a larger buffer size. I am learning C and I intentionally did it this way to try to gain a better understanding of dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have to zero your array of pointers (for example by using `calloc()`),

```
char **line = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*)*3); //allocate space for three char* pointers
```

otherwise the reallocs

```
*(line+i) = (char *)realloc(*(line+i), (inputLength+1)*sizeof(char)); //+1 for the empty character
```

use an uninitialized pointer, leading to undefined behaviour.
That it works with `i=0` is pure coindicence and is a typical pitfall when encountering UB.

Furthermore, when using `strcat()`, you have to make sure that the first parameter is already a zero-terminated string! This is not the case here, since at the first iteration, `realloc(NULL, ...);` leaves you with an uninitialized buffer. This can lead to `strcpy()` writing past the end of your allocated buffer and lead to heap corruption. A possible fix is to use `strcpy()` instead of `strcat()` (this should even be more efficient here):

```
   do{
        fgets(buffer, CHUNK, file);
        buffLength = strlen(buffer);
        lines[i] = realloc(lines[i], (lineLength + buffLength + 1));
        strcpy(lines[i]+lineLength, buffer);
        lineLength += buffLength;
    }while(bufferLength ==CHUNK-1);
```

The check `bufferLength == CHUNK-1` will not do what you want if the line (including the newline) is exactly `CHUNK-1` bytes long. A better check might be `while (buffer[buffLength-1] != '\n')`.

Btw. `line[i]` is by far better readable than `*(line+i)` (which is semantically identical).

Comment: so I should initialize the `char*` pointers to null first, for example? I was underf the impression it was enough to `malloc` them to something, and that `realloc` was just as good as `malloc`

Comment: Strictly speaking, `calloc` is not guaranteed to initialize pointer values to a null pointer. (A null pointer is not guaranteed to be represented by all-bits-zero.) You can guarantee portability by explicitly initializing each element to `NULL`.

Comment: @P. Gillich: `realloc(NULL, ...)` is as a good as `malloc`, but that's not what you're doing.  You're passing some random uninitialized value to `realloc`.

Comment: @P.Gillich At the beginning of your `for` loop, yes.

Comment: @jamesdlin I see. I will give it a try. I didn't know one had to initialize these to something before `malloc`. I thought the `malloc` would just write over whatever was there to start with

Comment: You asked for real-world systems, which to me means systems that actually exist (or existed) in the real world.  I did not claim that they are common systems.

Comment: @Ctx I'm very sorry, I tried your fixes and I still get the error. Maybe I implemented the fix wrong or misunderstood what you said to do?

Comment: @Ctx Could it be failing to compile because one needs a file to read, and maybe you don't have it? Elsewhere in my code, I am sending a filename from main and opening in the function I already typed out. I will upload the rest anyway, I have to retype it all because apparently vim doesn't support copy-paste.

Comment: The setting is only for the current session, so you don't disturb anyone with that. Furthermore, there is still the line `strcat(*(line+i), buffer);`, which would lead to a compilation error.

Comment: @Ctx I still have the same issue. I am giving up officially. I applied both fixes to my program, and it still runs into the same issue. I thank you wholeheartedly for your help, you really went above any beyond anyone to try to help. 
just out of curiosity, about what you said concerning `strcat` and having a null-terminated string...I tried setting `*(lines+i)="\0"`, thinking that might let `strcat` work properly, but that didn't work either. I remember one cannot modify a string like `char *str = "some string"`, but I thought this case would be different.

Comment: @P.Gillich This `*(lines+i)="\0"` sets the pointer to a static string and _that_ indeed could lead to your `realloc()` error.

Comment: @jamesdlin [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.3 Pointers(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3) does define a null pointer as the integer value `0` cast to `void *`. So while not technically the macro `NULL`, I know of no counter case where `calloc` would not results in initializing an array of pointers to `NULL`.

Comment: @David What that's saying is that the null pointer constant is 0, and that a null pointer is guaranteed to compare equal to the null pointer constant (i.e., 0). It doesn't mean that the null pointer will actually be 0 (i.e., will actually be represented with all zero bits). The C abstract machine just makes it appear as such. It *should* work in this case, because `realloc` is going to make the determination by comparing against the null pointer constant. In my opinion, if you have to ask questions like this, the code is broken and needs to be refactored, though.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The [null pointer *constant*](http://c-faq.com/sx1/index.html#null%20pointer%20constant) is defined to be 0.  The [null pointer](http://c-faq.com/sx1/index.html#null%20pointer) is not.  A compiler *converts* 0 into an appropriate null pointer when it's used as a pointer type.  Also see http://c-faq.com/null/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You allocate `line` (which is a misnomer since it's not a single line), which is a pointer to three `char*`s. You never initialize the contents of `line` (that is, you never make any of those three `char*`s point anywhere). Consequently, when you do `realloc(*(line + i), ...)`, the first argument is uninitialized garbage.

To use `realloc` to do an initial memory allocation, its first argument must be a null pointer.  You should explicitly initialize each element of `line` to `NULL` first.

Additionally, `*(line+i) = (char *)realloc(*(line+i), ...)` is still bad because if `realloc` fails to allocate memory, it will return a null pointer, clobber `*(line + i)`, and leak the old pointer.  You instead should split it into separate steps:

```
char* p = realloc(line[i], ...);
if (p == null) {
    // Handle failure somehow.
    exit(1);
} 
line[i] = p;
```

A few more notes:

- In C, you should avoid casting the result of `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc`.  It's not necessary since C allows implicit conversion from `void*` to other pointer types, and the explicit could mask an error where you accidentally omit `#include <stdlib.h>`.
- `sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1 byte.
- When you're allocating memory, it's safer to get into a habit of using `T* p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);` instead of `T* p = malloc(n * sizeof (T));`.  That way if the type of `p` ever changes, you won't silently be allocating the wrong amount of memory if you neglect to update the `malloc` (or `realloc` or `calloc`) call.